# Set variable zero-base for :gt or :lt selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm thinking this is probably an easy addition for someone with a bit more jQuery knowledge than me. But I have a navigation based on this piece of code: http://jsfiddle.net/JQq5n/508/

Whichever the current page is will have a class of 'active' in the li element (in this code the 4th li element). But I want to set the zero-base for the :gt and :lt selectors as that 'active' element. In essence, whichever page you're on will have it's title displayed as the first li element and you can click 'previous' or 'next' to get to the ones listed before or after. Does that make sense?

Also part 2 would be to only show the 'previous' link if there is actually something previous to get to. Thanks in advance for any help...

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="active">4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>14</li>
<li>15</li>
<li>16</li>
<li>17</li>
<li>18</li>
<li>19</li>
<li>20</li>
<li>21</li>
</ul>
<a class="prev">prev</a> | <a class="next">next</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
first.prev().nextAll().hide()
});

$('.next').click(function() {
var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
```

**Solution here:** http://jsfiddle.net/qrSAz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using jQuery's [`slice(start [, end ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) instead of selecting the previous and next elements

Personally I rather use classes than `show()` and `hide()`.

**Basic Idea:**

```
var lis = $("li");
var index = lis.filter(".active").index();
var start = index-2;
var end = index+3;
lis.removeClass("show").slice(start,end).addClass("show");
```

**Adding Additional Logic:**

Check to see if the start and end are in range, if not pad the left or right so the right number of numbers always show.

```
function showRange() {

    var range = 4;
    var lis = $("#pages li");

    if (lis.length > range) {

        var activeIndex = lis.filter(".active").index();
        var liCount = lis.length - 1;

        var start = activeIndex - (range / 2);
        var end = activeIndex + (range / 2);

        if (start < 0) {
            end -= start;
            start = 0;
        } else if (end >= liCount) {
            start += liCount - end;
            end = liCount;
        }

        lis.filter(".show").removeClass("show");
        lis.slice(start, end + 1).addClass("show");

    }
}
```

**Working example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYsrG/4/)

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if i was going about it wrong by using :gt... So could you help me modify tis a bit further? Basically, I don't need the prev/next buttons to select the next item like it's doing, i actually need them to go to the next five list items, kind of like pagination how the original fiddle was. Because if a user clicks on one of the elements it would refresh page, change that clicked element to active and hopefully have that active element as the first item in the list - and paginate back and forth from there.

Comment: You, my friend, are wonderful. That solves it completely! Thanks for you help.

Comment: Actually, one other thing. Do you know how to solve for if the active element is within five from the end it would add the 'show' class to the make it fill the five slots. Example: the active element is the last li element - on page load it would only show one navigation element, ideally it would also show the four previous as well. I can't wrap my head around how that would work as this is my first time fiddling with 'slice'. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If count > length, subtract from the index the difference.